# Payment method nonces expire after 24 hours in Brain Tree

Tags: braintree

We are making a bidding app in which highest bid will commit but after the completion of auction time (suppose 2 days).

As user may have provided me Payment method nonce 48 hours ago, than I have to save nonce and commit after 48 hours. Is there any solution to handle it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally with help of Braintree Support I find a way to handle this. Payment method nonce actually expires after 24 hours but there is an alternate way to use **payment method token** instead of **payment method nonce** to commit transaction after desired time. I'm working on Rails.

First, create a customer with given payment method nonce from client

```
result = Braintree::Customer.create(
            :first_name => "Faisal",
            :last_name => "Iqbal",
            :payment_method_nonce => 'fake-valid-nonce' )
```

It will create a customer on **vault** of your Braintree account and generate a **payment_method_token**, you can get it as

```
token_generated=result.customer.payment_methods[0].token
```

then use it to commit transaction at any time using

```
transation = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
            :amount => "5000.00",
            :payment_method_token => token_generated)
```

Comment: how can i get generated token for server instead of getnonse in android? @Muhammad Faisal Iqbal

Comment: @SachinSuthar I 'm not getting that what you want, a PAYMENT_METHOD_NONCE for creating a customer or PAYMENT_METHOD_TOKEN for transacation. Its already on server

Comment: i want to know last payment token not talking about client token

Comment: In my case it doesnt work, because creating transactions requires an amount. If i want to gain the token first and capture any amount in the future, is it possible?